# Scala: How to interpret foldLeft

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I have two examples of `foldLeft` that I cannot really grasp the logic.

**First example:**

```
val donuts: List[String] = List("Plain", "Strawberry", "Glazed")
println(donuts.foldLeft("")((acc, curr) =>  s" $acc, $curr Donut ")) // acc for accumulated, curr for current
```

This will give

> ```
>  , Plain Donut , Strawberry Donut , Glazed Donut
> ```

Does not `foldLeft` accumulate value that was earlier?
I was expecting the result to be

> ```
>  , Plain Donut ,  Plain Strawberry Donut , Strawberry Glazed Donut
> ```

**Second example:**

```
def multi(num:Int,num1:Int):Int=num*10

(1 until 3).foldLeft(1)(multi)
```

Can someone explain what is happening in every step? I cannot see how this can become 100. Also, the second argument `multi` is a function. Why does it not take any input variables (num and num1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does not `foldLeft` accumulate value that was earlier?

yes it does. It [uses](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) result of previous iteration and current element and produces new result (using the binary operator you have provided) so for the first example next steps are happening:

0. the start value of accumulator - `""`
1. `acc = ""`, `curr = "Plain"` -> `" , Plain Donut "`
2. `acc = " , Plain Donut "`, `curr = "Strawberry"` -> `" , Plain Donut , Strawberry Donut "`
3. `acc = " , Plain Donut , Strawberry Donut "`, `curr = "Strawberry"` -> `" , Plain Donut , Strawberry Donut , Glazed Donut"`

For the second example current value is simply ignored - i.e. `multi` can be rewritten as `def multi(acc:Int, curr:Int):Int = acc*10` where `curr` is not actually used so `foldLeft` simply multiplies starting value (`1`) by 10 `n` times where `n` is number of elements in the sequence (i.e. `(1 until 3).length` which is 2).

> Why does it not take any input variables (num and num1)?

[`foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) is a [function which accepts a function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html#functions-that-accept-functions). It accepts
a [generic](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) function which in turn accepts two parameters and returns result of the same type as the first parameter (`op: (B, A) => B`, where `B` is the the result type and `A` is sequence element type). `multi` matches this definition when `B` == `A` == `Int` and is passed to the `foldLeft` which will internally provide the input variables on the each step.

Answer (score 0):

A left fold needs three things: a list to works on, an initial value, and a function.

That function takes each element of the list and applies it to the initial value. Each time, the initial value is the result of the previous fucntion application.

Summing a list is a great toy example.

```
val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val total = nums.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b)
```

`total` is `10`.

That initial value has to pass all of the state you need. Currently, you pass the accumulated string. What you should be passing is a *tuple* giving your function extra information to work with: the accumulated string, and a string representing the *previous* element in the list.

Your result would look something like:

```
("Plain donut, ...", "Glazed")
```

Then you just need to select out the accumulated string and discard the second element.